# How do I call a class method from the HTML defined in its constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, class, constructor, event-handling

```
class Hello {
  constructor() {
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.htmlContent = `<a onclick="this.handleClick">Button</a>`;
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log('world');
  }
}
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

The "Button" link gets added to the page like so:

```
const myHello = new Hello();
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = myHello.htmlContent;
```

However clicking "Button" does not log "world" in the console.

Alternatively, these do not work:

```
onclick="()=> this.handleClick()"
onclick="this.handleClick()"
```

My guess is that this can only be accomplished with an `addEventListener` after the `innerHTML` is set on `#main`, because until then `myHello.htmlContent` is just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `HTMLElement` part of `Hello` and bind the event handler as soon as `innerHTML` by `Hello` *constructor*.

```js
class Hello {
  constructor(ele) {
    this.ele = ele;
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    ele.innerHTML = `<a onclick="this.handleClick">Button</a>`;
    ele.querySelector("a").addEventListener( "click", this.handleClick );
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log('world');
  }
}

var ele = document.getElementById('main');
const myHello = new Hello( ele );
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: @besseddrest You are welcome, glad it worked for you.